# How to change between pie-charts with the change in user selection in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a dataset like this,

| Emp Code | Name | Competency | Practice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Matt | Data | AI |
| 2 | Avery | Data | AI |
| 3 | Aryub | Data | Analytics |
| 4 | Jacob | Cloud | AWS |
| 5 | Zara | Data | Engineering |
| 6 | Ali | Cloud | DevOps |
| 7 | John | Cloud | DevOps |
| 8 | Alisha | Marketing | Services |
| 9 | Novak | Marketing | Advertisement |
| 10 | Alex | HR | HRBP |
| 11 | Emma | HR | Recruitment |

I have one slicer which allows the user to select between different competencies. I also have a pie-chart that displays ***Total Employees per Competency.***, as shown in the following image,

[image]

What I need is,

- If the user has not selected any competency, Pie-chart should display ***Total Employees per Competency***
- If the user has selected any competency, Pie-chart should display ***Total Employees per Practice***

Is it possible to do in the Power BI?

One solution I know of is to use *buttons and bookmarks* to navigate between different bookmarks, with each bookmark having a pie-chart against each competency selection. But I can't use this approach because of two reasons, 1) I can't place Buttons in a drop down slicer, which is a requirement for me. 2) Bookmarks can't be dynamic (so for example, if a new Competency comes in the data later on, that wil not be added automatically)

Another solution I could think of is using *Field Parameters* but then the problem is, I could not find any way to control the value of Field Parameter using another slicer (which is what I want to)

Can anyone help in this? Thanks

**If you would like to download the Example Power BI Workbook, you may do so here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DnTGDlaiTqL5GsuAw6DHko0GqHCS3d3h/view?usp=sharing**